# What's the shortcut to autocomplete the entire line in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

There used to be a shortcut or a way that auto-fills the entire line for you while you are writing

(without having to select it from the dropdown)

example

`Toast.`
becomes `Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the "Complete statement" shortcut:

Windows/Linux: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Though from your example, Toast would become: Toast.makeText();

Whereas without the dot, Toast would become: Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Then you'd select your param values, hitting enter to progress through each one.

You can also open the `Keymap` settings and in the menus, go through the hierarchy `Main Menu` > `Code` > `Code Completion`. There are multiple options, so you can pick what you prefer.

Source: [Android Studio Keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)